# Do Kubernetes PreStop hooks prevent ALL containers in a pod from stopping, or only the container it's set on?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

The Kubernetes documentation about [PreStop](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/) hooks claims the following:

> PreStop hooks are not executed asynchronously from the signal to stop
> the Container; the hook must complete its execution before the TERM
> signal can be sent.

However, it does not say anything about other containers in the pod.
Suppose `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` has not yet passed.

Are all containers in a pod protected from termination until the `PreStop` hook for each container finishes? Or does each PreStop hook only protect its own container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `preStop` hook only protects the container for which it's declared.

For example, in the following set up:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: lifecycle-demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name: lifecycle-demo-container
    image: nginx
    lifecycle:
      preStop:
        exec:
          command: ["/bin/sh","-c","sleep 15"]
  - name: other-container
    image: mysql
    env:
    - name: MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
      value: "true"
```

If I terminate the pod, the mysql receives SIGTERM and shuts down immediately while the nginx container stays alive for extra 15 seconds due to its `preStop` hook